# Karabiner help key remapping

Tags: keyboard, remap

I broke my "j" button on my macbook pro, any idea how I can replace the j with right-command + "k"?

I tried a couple of different things but could not get it to work.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your `private.xml`, something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>New J</name>
    <identifier>private.new_j_key</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::J</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```